# Could not push image: denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: docker, docker-api, docker-java

I'm using `docker-java` to create an image on a docker host which is running on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM. The image creation works just fine and I can list the image created via `docker-java`. But when I try to push the image to a private registry(Harbor) I get

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not push image: denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I have added my current user to the `usergroup docker` and can manually push the image with the following command from the terminal(note no sudo).

```
docker login
docker push some_ip/app/test:test
```

But when I make the following call from my java code I get the above mentioned error.

```
dockerClient.pushImageCmd("10.107.173.190/container-apps/test:testapp")                  
                    .exec(pushImageResultCallback).awaitSuccess();
```

**Possible cues:**

- Which profile does docker daemon use when being invoked by the API? How can I make sure it has sufficient access?

Comment: Did you use `.withRegistryUrl("https://10.107.173.190/v2/")
    .withRegistryUsername("user")
    .withRegistryPassword("pass")` while creating the dockerClient?

Comment: Yes I  did.. I actually solved this problem by refering to an [open issue](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/870) regarding this on their github repo..